# Microsoft Store Services SDK in UWP app MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, nuget

When trtying to use the Microsoft store services SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/microsoft-store-services-sdk?redirectedfrom=MSDN I am able to run my code locally fine, however when it is built and packaged as an AppX on a build server, and then I deploy the package to my machine, I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception (Exception message: Method 'StoreServicesExperimentVariation.GetCachedVariationAsync(string)' from assembly 'Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in InsiderRingDebugService.<RunExperimentAsync>d__4.MoveNext(). There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.)    App.xaml.cs 941
```

Can someone please provide some advice on why that might be? I have noted that this is a framework package and it does seem to be present in my WindowsApps directory. Thank you.

Edit: To clarify, I followed the 'install via nuget' and 'Add the assembly reference to your project' instructions on the docs linked

Answer (score 0):

Update: Had to be referenced in the core project as well as the UWP project. Now works!